# QGraphicsScene selectionChanged() event

Tags: c++, qt

I need to know when a `QGraphicItem` is selected from my `Scene`. I'm using the signal from the method `selectionChange()` but this does nothing. This my code:

scene.h

```
class Scene : public QGraphicsScene{
public:
    Scene(QGraphicsScene *scene = 0);
    ~Scene();
private slots:
    void test();
};
```

scene.cpp

```
Scene::Scene(QGraphicsScene* scene):QGraphicsScene(scene)
{
    connect(this, SIGNAL(QGraphicsScene::selectionChanged()), this, SLOT(test()));
}

void Scene::test() {
    qDebug() << "I'm here ";
}
```

I suppose that the problem is that my scene inherits from `QGraphicScene`, or that it's a bad idea define the connection in the constructor.

Comment: The items you add to the scene should have their `QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable` flag set, so take a look at [setFlags](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setFlags).

Comment: yes @scopchanov, I set this in all my items item->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);

Comment: I think you should establish your connection like this: `connect(this, SIGNAL(selectionChanged()), this, SLOT(test()));`

Comment: ty @vahancho, this is correct. I tester this in the class where i crearte my scene and go fine, but i need that connect stay in Scene class no outside :S.

Comment: @DavidLeonOrtega, sorry, I don't understand you:) What do you need? Please rephrase the sentence.

Comment: @vahancho first he tested it with a stock _QGraphicsScene_ and then decided to subclass _QGraphicsScene_, pasting in it the `connect` line as it was before without removing the already unnecessary qualifier `QGraphicsScene::` from the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @Angew, the problem is in the text passed to the `SIGNAL` macro.

If you're using Qt 5, the preferred method would be to use the newer connection syntax, which benefits from compile time error checking

```
connect(this, &GraphicsScene::SelectionChanged, this, &Scene::Test);
```

This connection method uses addresses of functions, which has the additional benefit of being able to connect to functions that haven't been declared as a `SLOT`. However, it may be desirable to still define slots, [as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47196736/are-public-slots-sections-still-necessary-in-qt5).

Answer (score 5):

`SIGNAL` and `SLOT` are macros and thus text-based processing, which makes them quite picky. It's generally a good idea to `assert` that all your connections succeed. In your case, the problem is the extraneous qualification. Drop it:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(selectionChanged()), this, SLOT(test()));
```

Comment: Isn't it even better for him to use the new syntax in order to be able to get a compile time error when something is not correct?

Comment: @scopchanov *If* they're using Qt5, probably. I'm still stuck on Qt4, and haven't studied the details of Qt5 yet, so I leave the floor open for better answers...

Comment: Good point! I always forget, that people are using different versions. :)