# How to directly notify a QGraphicsItem when it is selected or de-selected

Tags: qt, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

In my `QGraphicsScene` I have some `QGraphicsItem` that are selectable and movable because of the following two flags:

```
setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);
setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
```

Is it possible to notify the `QGraphicsItem` when it is selected or de-selected? I need to use this state to decide whether the child views of the `QGraphicsItem` are visible. I tried to avoid using the notification on `QGraphicsScene` as I don't want to iterate through it's children QGrphicsItem.

Comment: Look at `QGraphicsScene::focusItemChanged`. It signals when the focus of a `QGraphicsItem` changes, which isn't exactly what you want but may be useful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QGraphicsScene selectionChanged() event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47390499/qgraphicsscene-selectionchanged-event)

Comment: @MohammadKanan I am looking for a way to signal the QGraphicsItem directly that it's selected or de-selected. The link you sent works on the scene level. Thanks nevertheless!