# Qt C++ unable to connect to QTcpServer using Telnet

Tags: c++, qt, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

I have watched VoidRealm's Youtube video, `C++ Qt 67 - QTCPServer - a basic TCP server application` and followed his instructions, however, I can't connect to the QTcpServer I created using Telnet.

My Code:

```cpp
//myserver.h

#ifndef MYSERVER_H
#define MYSERVER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QTcpSocket>

class MyServer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyServer(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    void newConnection();
signals:

private:
    QTcpServer *server;
};
#endif // MYSERVER_H
```

```cpp
//myserver.cpp

#include "myserver.h"

MyServer::MyServer(QObject *parent)
    : QObject{parent}
{
    server = new QTcpServer(this);

    connect(server,SIGNAL(newConnection()),this,SLOT(newConnection()));

    if(!server->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 1234))
    {
        qDebug() << "Server could not start!";
    }else{
        qDebug() << "Server started!";
    }
}

void MyServer::newConnection()
{
    QTcpSocket *socket = server->nextPendingConnection();

    socket->write("hello client\r\n");
    socket->flush();

    socket->waitForBytesWritten(3000);

    socket->close();
}
```

Running this code, in the Console screen I get

```
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::connect: No such slot MyServer::newConnection() in ..\First_Server\myserver.cpp:8
Server started!
```

but when I open a command prompt and do the following steps:

```
...>telnet
```

```
Welcome to Microsoft Telnet Client

Escape Character is 'CTRL+]'

Microsoft Telnet> open 127.0.0.1 1234
Connecting To 127.0.0.1...
```

It is not connecting.
Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong?
I am using Qt 6.3.0.

Comment: Your console msg told you: "no such slot". Looks like you have a typo and forgot `public slots:` section. That's because you use old connection syntax, with the new one, it is no longer a requirement, but still good to have for clarity. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47196736/are-public-slots-sections-still-necessary-in-qt5

Comment: As for telnet connection, technically should work, but you are on windows, so ... I assume that in `main` you have `QApplication::exec`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You error message indicates the issue:

> qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::connect: No such slot MyServer::newConnection() in ..\First_Server\myserver.cpp:8
> Server started!

You have created the connection between the signal and slot here.

```
connect(server,SIGNAL(newConnection()),this,SLOT(newConnection()));
```

First of all, it is not a good idea to have the same slot name as the signal as it becomes confusing. I would call your slot as "handleNewConnection" for example. Secondly, you ought to use the ["new" signal-slot syntax](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/signalsandslots.html). Thirdly, and most importantly, you have not declared your newConnection() method to be a slot. You would need to declare it so in your header file:

```
private Q_SLOTS:
    void newConnection();
```

You can also make the slots public if it has to be accessed from outside, it looks like that you would only use it privately here.

Comment: Excellent idea to suggest the "new" (well... it was introduced in Qt 5? or late Qt 4?) Signal-slot syntax as it helps avoid all kind of headaches ("Why the hell does it not work...?  *5 hours later* Ah, typo in the name for the SLOT() macro.... ARGH) - maybe you could include an example to help get the idea across?